# Check if a non app store application is installed in windows 10 machine

Tags: javascript, windows, oracle-maf

I have installed a windows desktop application(not from app store). 
How can I check if this app is installed from other application using javascript?

Is there any plugin available for Windows application like cordova AppAvailability for Android/iOS?

Comment: by javascript, do you mean node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx) to generate a list of installed apps [via the `wmic` command-line tool](https://superuser.com/questions/68611/get-list-of-installed-applications-from-windows-command-line), and go over this list to find the app you're searching.

If you're running NodeJS, you can use the [`node-cmd` package](https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/node-cmd) to execute the sequence of commands in the link above, and capture the string output so you can parse later.